# Cheese not launching- (Error restoring saved CRTC)

Tags: webcam, camera, segmentation-fault, cheese

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for about 4 months now and have launched cheese a few times without any issue.

```
priyanshu@Inspiron-7501:~$ cheese 

(cheese:499251): Cogl-WARNING **: 17:34:35.299: winsys/cogl-winsys-egl-kms.c:771: Error restoring saved CRTC
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This error message keeps showing when I try to open it now.
The other articles relating to errors in cheese have a different error message and I have not come accross a similar problem in recent Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reinstalling cheese:

```
sudo apt reinstall cheese
```

All this will do is reinstall cheese. It won't delete the directory containing the photos and videos it displays when you open it.

Comment: Shows the same error