# Turn off webcam on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, webcam, kill

I posted [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386514/cheese-not-launching-error-restoring-saved-crtc/1386619#1386619) to get cheese working on my pc. The solution I recieved didn't work so I tried installing KDE's camera app, 'Kamoso' and it too showed a long error message.

```
priyanshu@Inspiron-7501:~$ kamoso 
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
new device "Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate" "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/video4linux/video0" "/dev/video0"
Playing device changed "/dev/video0"
failed to acquire GL context to resolve capabilities, using defaults..
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/ToolBarPageHeader.qml:44:9: QML ActionToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "actions"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/ToolBarPageHeader.qml:44:9: QML ActionToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "actions"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/ToolBarPageHeader.qml:44:9: QML ActionToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "actions"
error: no element "bulge"
error: no element "frei0r-filter-cartoon"
error: no element "frei0r-filter-twolay0r"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/PageRowGlobalToolBarUI.qml:113: TypeError: Cannot read property 'globalToolBarStyle' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/PageRowGlobalToolBarUI.qml:58:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QQmlListProperty<QObject>
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/PageRowGlobalToolBarUI.qml:49:13: Unable to assign [undefined] to bool
kf5.kdbusaddons: Can not find 'kdeinit5' executable at  "/home/priyanshu/.local/bin:/home/priyanshu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" "/usr/bin, /usr/lib/qt5/bin"
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

But it has also turned my webcam on an I can't get it to turn off.
I tried suspending my laptop but that didn't work.
Rebooting might resolve the problem but I wanted to get to the root of it so I started looking for some articles online.

I tried '''sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo```
but it didn't wor and I got this:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module uvcvideo is in use
```

Then I listed the processes using this module:

```
priyanshu@Inspiron-7501:~$ lsmod | grep uvcvideo
uvcvideo               98304  1
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       61440  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              245760  4 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

But it again  returned a bunch of modules which I again can't remove as they all are in use. On running lsmod on each of them I just get looping through different modules.

Is there a way to kill all processes using a module automatically?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Unplug" the USB connection: `echo "1-5" >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`. Count to five, then: `echo "1-5" >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind`.

Comment: How did you find the "device id" for the `echo` command @matigo ?

Comment: There is no external device connected to my laptop. The problem is with the internal webcam. How does unbinding and binding usb help?

Comment: @FedKad it's in the output in the first code block: `... usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/ ...`

Comment: @PriyanshuSahani your camera shows as being a USB device. USB devices are not all external. Heck, many keyboards, touchpads, nubs, cameras, fingerprint sensors, temperature sensors and all sorts of other things that are built into a notebook are connected over USB. The bus is extensible, cheap, and easily supported. With 3.1 having such a large amount of bandwidth, the "U" in USB actually makes sense now ...

Comment: `priyanshu@Inspiron-7501:~$ sudo echo "1-5" >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
bash: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind: Permission denied
`

Comment: @matigo as you said 'keybords' are built into a pc. So won't my keyboard get disconnected too after running the first command?

Comment: Your keyboard is not using bus `1` port `5`, so would not be disconnected. USB devices can be controlled individually so long as the controller allows it. Yours, it seems, does not want to play nice. Believe it or not, I do try to pay attention to details and ask additional questions before breaking things 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133475/discussion-between-priyanshu-sahani-and-matigo).

Comment: usbreset from usb-utils can be used to reset an usb device.